# Continuous Integration of JavaScript Tests with MSBuild / Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration

Is there a way to get JavaScript tests to do continuous integration with MSBuild or in Visual Studio? What I want to do is have it so anytime my JavaScript or my JavaScript tests change they are built again and ran and if they fall below certain values of acceptance criteria (code coverage, assertions passing, test's passing, etc.) it'll fail my build. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What build server are you using? What JavaScript testing framework are you using? How do the tests get run? In a browser? In another application?

Comment: TFS is the build server, QUnit is the testing framework, tests get run both through the browser using Chutzpah and through Visual Studio's test suite with Chutzpah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Chutzpah has a command-line runner, so you can create a PowerShell script which gets called from your build server to run the tests.  See the [Chutzpah documentation](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/documentation) for more information.  I'm not sure how you would integrate the test results with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Command Line build step to run my javascript tests with chutzpah.

Add this and point to something like

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages\Chutzpah.4.0.3\tools\chutzpah.console.exe
```

or whereever you have chutzpah setup to be run on build server. You can then add an argument to tell the chutzpah console where the tests are

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\YourApp.UnitTests\Tests**strong text**
```